# jquery submit(); not working for firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, form-submit

I am new in web development i am trying to handle a form submit using jquery and javascript.

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#UnitFrom').submit(function (e) {
 alert(); //Works for Chrome and IE... But not in firefox...
 e.preventDefault(); // Form Is not submitted in Chrome and IE.. for firefox it submits the from to same url that i am in..
  });

 });
```

My HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="UnitFrom">
 <input type="submit" id="CalculateUnit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any alternate to handle form submitting.

Comment: @Sergio It's no different. At least give a reason why they should try that

Comment: `Error: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]`

Comment: Just for "good practice" add your .js files on your head tags 

I herd you should have them at the end of your body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dude you can not have `alert()` first and than `e.preventDefault();`.

`e.preventDefault();` has to be first and `alert()` second.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mpatm/

Comment: Thanks Alot

Works with $('#UnitFrom').on("submit",function (e) Not With this..
$('#UnitFrom').submit(function (e) 
Is there any technical Difference between these two??

Comment: That's just incorrect. Of course you can have them in any order. The problem is that Firefox **requires** an argument passed to it, so an exception is thrown and the `e.preventDefault()` doesn't execute. It doesn't mean it can't come second

Comment: Sorry this is working too .. Thanks
 $('#UnitFrom').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submission
    alert('some'); // do some stuff
 });

Comment: @ShankerPaudel `.submit(func...` is just a shortcut for `.on("submit", func...`. There's a limited number of shortcuts, while `.on()` allows you to listen for any event type

Comment: Proof that you **CAN** have the `alert` before `preventDefault` if your alert doesn't throw an exception: http://jsfiddle.net/nHkhg/

Answer (score 2):

Put something in your alert:

```
alert("TEXT HERE");
```

If you check your console, you should see an error similar to this:

> Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]

When the exception is thrown, the method execution ends without calling `preventDefault`, allowing the form to submit.  This is why it is a best practice to place `preventDefault` at the top of your function, **but it is not required**.  If it is first and there is an exception, the default behavior is still prevented.

Answer (score 2):

You should write:

```
 $('#UnitFrom').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submission
    alert('some'); // do some stuff
 });
```

OR

```
 $('#UnitFrom').submit(function () {
    alert('some');
    return false; // prevent form submission
 });
```

Comment: @ShankerPaudel You should accept this answer or JamesMontagne's. The **real** problem is that Firefox **requires** an argument passed to `alert`, so an exception is thrown and the `e.preventDefault();` doesn't execute

Comment: I am not so reputed to Vote! :) Sorry about that.

Comment: Should be noted that `return false` will also `stopPropagation` in addition to `preventDefault`.